# Reliable real values generator for Excel for Office 2007 and Vista SP1

Tags: excel, excel-2007, random

can you please tell me which add-in you are using to generate real/integer values in Excel 2007 (running on Vista SP1)? I have tried a couple of them and particularly Random Generator from AbleBits.com  but there are some problems with entering lowest and highest values there. I guess this is due to Office 2007 & Vista configuration.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What keeps your from using the built-in random number generator functions?

From the Excel docs:

> Randomize Statement Example: This
>   example uses the Randomize statement
>   to initialize the random-number
>   generator. Because the number argument
>   has been omitted, Randomize uses the
>   return value from the Timer function
>   as the new seed value.

```
Dim MyValue
Randomize    ' Initialize random-number generator. '

MyValue = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)    ' Generate random value between 1 and 6. '
```

If you won't/cannot use VBA, elaborating *what* you'd like to use would be a good thing.

EDIT:

There is also a cell function ("RAND") available, doing the same thing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the RAND function, which is the most obvious solution.